# ZF2 User Register and creation of a Subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework2, subdomain, user-registration

Im using the ZF 2 Framework and have the follow scenario.

1. Company can register
2. After Register it creates a subdomain (need changes in the
   .htaccess)

**Example :**

- site.com => Frontend
- company_a.site.com => Frontend for Company (company_id=1)
- compaby_b.site.com => Frontend for Company (company_id=2)

What i want is that when a Users goes to company_a.site.com or company_b.site.com, that the Route is the same in the Application but the Data from DB depens on the subdomain name.

**How i think it must work :**

1. User comes to company_a.site.com
2. In the Main Controller i will make a Query to DB to see if exists a company with name "company_a" and if is so then assign a
   global variable with the company ID from the DB. So i can based on
   that ID load the content for the frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution with the ZF 2 Route Hostname type

Answer (score 1):

I done something similar in my current project.  I used a service to get the site details from a MySQL database using doctrine based on the domain name.

My service is

```
namespace Application\Service;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Application\Entity\Sites;

class SiteFactory implements FactoryInterface
{

    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    protected $entityManager = NULL;

    /**
     * 
     * @param \Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     * @return \Application\Entity\Sites
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $request = $serviceLocator->get('Request');
        $site = new Sites();

        if (method_exists($request, 'getUri')) {
            $domainName = ltrim($request->getUri()->getHost(), 'www.');
            $entityManager = $serviceLocator->get('entityManager');
            $repository = $entityManager->getRepository('Application\Entity\Sites');
            $site = $repository->findOneByDomainName($domainName); 
        }

        return $site;
    }

}
```

In my module.config I have

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'site' => 'Application\Service\SiteFactory',
    ),
),
```

and to get the site in my controller I use

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('site');
```

to return the sites doctrine entity or an empty entity if no site found.

I hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for your sollution, but the problem for me is the Routing, how to setup a Routing for all the subdomains.